# How to save ChainMap objects?

Tags: python, save, chain

I have a list of `ChainMap` objects in python that I'm using for analysis. I need to save them to disk somehow for later use. Is there any possibility to do this?

Comment: [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#module-pickle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the pickle lib. Here is a toy example that saves `cm.pickle` as a binary file and reads it again as the `unpickled` variable.

```
from collections import ChainMap
import pickle

nums = {"one": 1, "two": 2}
lets = {"a": "A", "b": "B"}

cm = ChainMap(nums, lets)

with open('cm.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(cm, f)

with open('cm.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    unpickled = pickle.load(f)

print(unpickled)
ChainMap({'one': 1, 'two': 2}, {'a': 'A', 'b': 'B'})
```